# Downloading treasury data with Pandas read_csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm trying to download treasury data from [this page](http://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/h15/data.htm) using Pandas read_csv.

```
url = "http://www.federalreserve.gov/datadownload/Output.aspx?rel=H15&series=bcb44e57fb57efbe90002369321bfb3f&lastObs=&from=&to=&filetype=csv&label=include&layout=seriescolumn"
res = requests.get(url)
csvio = StringIO(res.content)
dataframe = pd.read_csv(csvio, header=5, index_col=0, parse_dates=True)

columns_dic = {"RIFLGFCY10_N.B":'BC_10YEAR'}
dataframe = dataframe.rename(columns=columns_dic)

print (dataframe.head())
```

The output looks a little strange to me:

```
            BC_10YEAR
Time Period          
1962-01-02       4.06
1962-01-03       4.03
1962-01-04       3.99
1962-01-05       4.02
1962-01-08       4.03
```

I don't understand why the header is split between two rows when I print it. Also, it's not clear to me that the dates are being properly parsed. Is there a way I can fix my call to read_csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header is split because of your `index_col=0` argument. Try without an index column

```
In [20]: dataframe = read_csv(csvio, header=5, index_col=None, parse_dates=True)

In [21]: dataframe
Out[21]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 13379 entries, 0 to 13378
Data columns:
Time Period       13379  non-null values
RIFLGFCY10_N.B    13379  non-null values
dtypes: object(2)

In [22]: dataframe.head()
Out[22]: 
  Time Period RIFLGFCY10_N.B
0  1962-01-02           4.06
1  1962-01-03           4.03
2  1962-01-04           3.99
3  1962-01-05           4.02
4  1962-01-08           4.03
```

and the first column of data from the StringIO object becomes a column in the DataFrame, instead of becoming the index.

Comment: I'd like to make the first column the index though

Comment: Is that just how pandas prints an index? It looks odd to me that it's split between two rows and I'm not sure if that's okay or not.

Comment: @BenMcCann yes, that is just how pandas prints an index that has a name. Also you don't need requests here. `pd.read_csv(url, header=5, index_col=0, parse_dates=True)` should suffice